# Flutter: how to make this part of the code scrollable?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a flutter app and I need to make a part of the code scrollable. The full code:

```
 return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ...
            ],
          ),
          for (var day in data)
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Text(
                  day.getDate(),
                  style: getDataLabelStyle(),
                ),
                Text(
                  day.getStarting(),
                  style: getDataLabelStyle(),
                ),
                Text(
                  day.getEnding(),
                  style: getDataLabelStyle(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

And this part should be scrollable:

```
          for (var day in data)
            Row(
              ...
              ],
            ),
```

Also you can see what part should be scrollable:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use ColumnBuilder and then Wrap it with singleChildScrollView like this:

```
Expanded(
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(children: List.generate(data.lenght, (index){
      return  Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Text(
            day.getDate(),
            style: getDataLabelStyle(),
          ),
          Text(
            day.getStarting(),
            style: getDataLabelStyle(),
          ),
          Text(
            day.getEnding(),
            style: getDataLabelStyle(),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }),),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your task using the [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) Class.

For your given code you can achieve this by wrapping your row into `Column` and again wrap it with `SingleChileScrollView`.

**The full solution is:**

```
....
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            for (var day in data)
              Row(
                children: [
                  .......
                ],
              ),
           ],
         ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the part with `SingleChildScrollView`. and if you are using `SingleChildScrollView` inside a `Column`, do not forget to wrap that with `Expanded`.

example,

```
Expanded(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            child: yourCustomWidget()
          ),
        ),
      ),
```